# How to use Array.map() in Lightning Component JS File

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, javascript-controller

I was going through [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f) blog to understand `foreach` loop, but the blog says that use of `Array.map()` is more efficient than for `foreach`. So, I tried implementing that in my Lightning Component, but it doesn't let me save and throws `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - ESLINT_ERROR --> Parsing error: Unexpected token =>  : Source`

I'm trying to implement like below:

**Use of forEach**

```
arr.forEach((num, index) => {
    return arr[index] = num * 2;
});
```

**Use of Array.map():**

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = arr.map(num => num * 2); 
consle.log('>> '+arr2);
```

**Here is what I'm originally trying to implement:**

```
let cleanedMID = mcWrapper.map(mId.newMID => this.cleanMerchantID(component, event, mId.newMID)); 
console.log('>>'+cleanedMID);
```

Is this(`Array.map()`) possible in lightning framework to implement.

Comment: Yes, both functions forEach() and map() are useable within Lightning Framework. You`ve got a typo somewhere. Please review your code.

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi Thanks for confirming that. Could you please review once the below code if it has some Typos.

`let cleanedMID = mcWrapper.map(mId.newMID => this.cleanMerchantID(component, event, mId.newMID));
console.log('>>'+cleanedMID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you're passing to the arrow function should be the object from the array, not a specific item from the element. Notably, `mId.newMID` would be invalid, as a parameter name must follow JavaScript's rules for [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier). Changing it to just `mId` should do the trick:

```
let cleanedMID = mcWrapper.map(
  mId => this.cleanMerchantID(component, event, mId.newMID));
```

Additional alterations may be required. Map expects the return value (here, whatever cleanMerchantID is) to be the new elements of the array. Without seeing that function, it's not entirely clear if this answer solves your problem, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, your answer just confirmed what I found out little later after posting this question. You have an answer for everything  :)